# Mouse with separate scroll wheel and middle button

Tags: mice

Can you recommend an optical mouse with three mouse buttons and a non-clickable scroll wheel?

Most mice available today have two buttons with a clickable scroll wheel between them. I am not happy with that design. It is simply too easy for me to accidentally click when I intended to scroll or vice-versa.

I would like a mouse with three real buttons and a non-clickable scroll wheel - ideally located between the left button and the middle button. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: It is easy to get a mouse with an extra button (sometimes even in the middle, but normally on the sides). Then you remap the button to be middle click. Either with the mouse config in windows 10, or with Autohot-key in earlier version of windows (I'm sure similar can be done on other OS's). My mouse has a broken middle click, so this is what I have done.

Comment: I'm certain you can do it in linux (I've seen it done), and I would be very odd if you couldn't in Mac. Most side buttons are are easier to press than top buttons -- several ergonomic mice move the main keys to the side for this reason.

Comment: I'm happy with my mouse (a cheap one I bought ~15 years ago) with a thumb button and a clickable wheel, but if you want three button on top, ok. That being said, have you tried different mice? They vary a lot in terms of how much force it takes to click the wheel, all the way from “pretty much can't scroll without clicking” to “will make your middle finger very strong”.

Comment: @Gilles I have tried a few, but not a lot compared to how many presumably exists. So far I haven't come across one with a middle button that worked as good as the mice from before the invention of the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer available new, but I've found the perfect mouse.  The **IBM/Lenovo ScrollPoint III Mouse**.  It has three real buttons, optical sensing at 800dpi, a very ergonomic 3D scrolling stick, and is built very sturdily.  They used to be the standard mouse that comes with IBM's lower-end PCs, so there were thousands made, and there are many still available NOS.

I would love to have an identical mouse in wireless, but I guess I'm stuck with the wired one. You can take it from my cold, dead hand.  I've bought a small pile of them new-in-box so I never run out.